# como vincular django signals con AJAX

Tags: ajax, django, api, djangorestframework, signals

estoy tratando de implementar un sistema de recopilacion de datos mediante dispositivos iot.
actualmente la transmision de datos es  mediante un API utilizando django RESTframewors. Eso funciona excelente
Me gustaria conocer alguna aproximacion para que se genere un trigger cuando reciba datos y estos en la pagina web del usuario se refresquen mediate ajax. tal vez el uso de signals pero no sabria como vincular ese signal con ajax.
Soy algo novato con javascript.
algun camino debo seguir?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes probar a Django Channels con WebSockets